# SQLAlchemy query, join on relationship and order by count

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two SQLAlchemy models set up as follows:

```
##############
# Post Model #
##############
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250))
    content = db.Column(db.String(5000))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.Integer)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref = 'post', lazy = 'dynamic')

###############
# Likes Model #
###############
class Like(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    voter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
```

As you can see, there's a model for posts and a model for user likes on those posts. I'd like to create a query that selects all posts, ordered by the number of likes that post has. In the shell, I can run:

```
SELECT post.*, 
       count(like.id) AS num_likes
FROM post
LEFT JOIN like
ON post.id = like.post_id
GROUP BY post.id;
```

What's the equivalent SQLAlchemy command?

Thanks!

Comment: SQLAlchemy has very good [documentation on writing queries](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying) with the ORM, including a section on [querying with joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins). You can also look at the [Query object API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html) to see that it has a [`group_by()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.group_by) method. Is there anything specific in creating this query in SQLAlchemy that you are having problems with?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The translation from raw query to Flask-SQLAlchemy is pretty much mechanical:

```
db.session.query(Post, db.func.count(Like.id)).outerjoin(Like).group_by(Post.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! I modified it slightly so I could use the Flask-SQLAlchemy BaseQuery paginate() method:

    ```Post.query.outerjoin(Like).group_by(Post.id).order_by(db.func.count(Like.id).desc(), Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(page_num, 10, False)```

But it's more or less the same. Thanks again!

Comment: No. It is confusing