# Flask SqlAlchemy - Group and Count using foreignkey

Tags: python, orm, group-by, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got two tables that are linked using a foreignkey:

```
class Region(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'regions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(55), nullable=False)
    items = db.relationship('Item', backref='region', lazy='dynamic')

class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    region_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('regions.id'))
```

I want to find out how many items are in a particular region. I can do this using the `region_id` field in the item table as follows:

```
field = Item.region_id
count = func.count(field)
query = db.session.query(count, field).group_by(field).all()
```

However, I don't really want to group using `Item.region_id`, I really want to group using the `name` column of the `Region` class using the `backref`. So something like:

```
field = Item.region.name
count = func.count(field)
query = db.session.query(count, field).group_by(field).all()
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290462/sqlalchemy-query-join-on-relationship-and-order-by-count